# Syntax with .htaccess URL rewrite

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting

I need to get the following URL rewrite syntax correct and am struggling.

```
xxxxx.com/public_html/food/
```

Needs to be rewritten as:

```
xxxxx.com/food/
```

I tried this and it doesn't work:

```
RewriteEngine On   
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  ^/public_html/food/(.*)$  
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://xxxxx.com/food/%1 [R=301,L]
```

My client is using Joomla (which I am not familiar with), so I need to do so using the .htaccess file per everything I have researched so far. I am just struggling getting the syntax to work correctly though.

Thanks!

Comment: Are you saying that an **incoming** URI has a superfluous `public_html/` in it, and you want to get rid of it? And you want to return a 301 status so that search engines will update their entries and users will re-bookmark it? What happens if you `RewriteRule ^public_html/food/(.*)$ /food/$1 [R=301,L]`?

Answer (score 0):

Try this, `.htaccess`

for **Rewrite**

```
RewriteEngine On   
RewriteRule ^food/?(.*)$ http://xxxxx.com/public_html/food/$1 [QSA,L]
```

for **Redirect** (add R=301)

```
RewriteEngine On   
RewriteRule ^food/?(.*)$ http://xxxxx.com/public_html/food/$1 [R=301,QSA,L]
```

**Edit:**

If you want to rewrite all urls (including /food)

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/public_html/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /public_html/$1 [QSA,L]
```

It will allow you to access site like,

**http://xxxxx.com/food/** will point to **http://xxxxx.com/public_html/food/**

**http://xxxxx.com/sample/** will point to **http://xxxxx.com/public_html/sample/**

**http://xxxxx.com/anything/cool/?product=123** will point to **http://xxxxx.com/public_html/anything/cool/?product=123/**